# Wordpress multiple custom post types with same permalink slug

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, permalinks

I have a Wordpress site that comprises of a bunch of pages and three custom post types:
*Fruit*
*Vegetables*
*Meat*
Is it possible to have the permalink structure for these three post types as follows:
/food/apple *- from the Fruit CPT*
/food/carrot *- from the Vegtable CPT*
/food/beef *- from the Meat CPT*.
I've been playing around with rewrite rules and my feeling is that /food would have to be made unique to each post type otherwise you get a conflict. Is that right?
Any help much appreciated!